# How to draw a globe in 2D?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, spheres, map-projections

I want to draw such globe:

[image: Globe example]

Let's say my input params are:

- center (x,y)
- radius
- number of meridians
- number of parallels.

I know such concepts as:

- 2D ellipse equation
- 4x4 projection matrix for 3D -> 2D perspective projection

I looked at [Wikipedia's list of map projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections), in many of them parallels are lines instead of curved lines.

Do you know which approach is the most simple for this problem?
How to choose formula for each meridian/parallel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @B.Mehta Thanks, but parallels look straight there.

Comment: Ah, my mistake.

Comment: Looks like a "Nicolosi"  projection to me (see [here](http://www.progonos.com/furuti/MapProj/Normal/ProjPM/projPM.html))

Comment: @B.Mehta: this is certainly not a Mollweide projection.

Comment: @achillehui Thanks, it's the same! The next challenge for me is to find formulae.

Comment: Frankly I wouldn't be surprised if this image was created by someone just drawing some arcs that looked right, without a specific formula.

Comment: I dig down the code I have ( I forget where I get the formula), For Nicolosi projection, the parallels are circular arcs, equidistance at central and boundary medians. the meridians are also circular arcs, equidistance at equator. As long as you know how to draw an arc passing 3 points, you are done.

Comment: @achillehui: In the figure in the question, the meridians are clearly not equidistant at the equator. It doesn't look like the parallels are equidistant either.

Comment: @Rahul hmm you are right, the meridian doesn't look equidistant on equator.  Perhaps they are drawn using a orthogonal projection. The parallels do look reasonably equidistant to me...

Comment: @achillehui Your formulae for Nicolosi projection are wonderful: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1674351/204563
Should I mark my question as duplicate then?

Comment: @Olia_Pavliuk ahh! I forget I have answered that question before. If that solve your problem, it is up to you to mark this as duplicate.

Comment: @achillehui Thanks again, you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

A relatively simple option (though doesn't seem to be exactly your case) is the stereographic projection. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection. It is a central projection onto a meridional plane, with the projection center on the sphere.

The meridians and parallels are all circular arcs (in fact Apollonius circles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius#Circles_sharing_a_radical_axis). They keep meeting at right angles.

[image]